# Можно ли вернуться в блок try из блока catch после обработки исключения?

Tags: c#, исключения, firebird, try-catch

Слышал, что есть возможность после выбрасывания `Exception` обработать его в `catch`, и вернуться в точку возникновения самого `Exception` для продолжения.

Примерно так должно выглядеть:

```
try
{
   // Вызываем исключение
   // Возвращаемся сюда для продолжения исполнения кода
}
catch (SomeEx)
{
   // Обработка исключения и возврат обратно в вышестоящий блок try{}
}
```

**Вопрос**: в самом ли деле есть такой способ?

Нужно примерно в такой ситуации: есть глубоко зарытый код, который открывает подключение к базе данных. Чуть ниже находится код загрузки данных из базы. Так вот, хочется сделать проверку на корректность базы (версии базы) на уровне открытия подключения: если версия будет некорректна, то нужно выдать пользователю сообщение, что версия старая, но можно продолжить выполнение кода по загрузки данных из неё (это сообщение не критично).

Думал ещё про постпроверку, но дело в том, что подключение открывается в самых разных местах, и постпроверку версии придётся также размазать по всему коду, что не есть хорошо.

Comment: "подключение открывается в самых разных местах" — не очень хорошо. Сделайте компоненту, которая будет отвечать за подключение и всё такое. Подключение будет идти только через эту компоненту. И код модульнее получится заодно.

Comment: после исключения нет никакого "возвращения в точку возникновения". Исключение или обрабатывается на месте и код работает дальше, как-будто исключения не было, или не обрабатывается и исключение передается вызывающей функции.

Comment: @vladd, а как поступить? у меня коннект открывается:

* Когда пользователь открывает диалог выбора файла.
* Когда пользователь перетаскивает файл на форму.
* Когда файл приходит приложению во время старта в качестве параметра.
* + система плагинов реализована, где также может производиться открытие подключения, если в качестве параметра к плагину не был передан коннект или был передан нуловый коннект.

Да, попробую еще сделать прослойку.Сейчас сделал пока через шаблон, реализовал свой метод для открытия подключения, осталось найти все места где открывается подключение, и заменить на свой мето

Comment: @pincher1519: так и надо делать. Логику бросания-небросания исключений упакуйте в прослойку.

Comment: Все равно не хорошо получается, мне нужно вывести мессэйджбокс пользователю о некорректности версии базы. Его соответственно нужно выводить на этапе работы кода главного окна приложения... Т.е. придётся тащить сообщение из самых недр до главного окна программы...

Comment: Сделаю наверное событие, главное окно подпишу на него и оно при получении события будет решать нужно дальше код отрабатывать или выйти с ошибкой из нех недр.

Comment: Ну, а в чём проблема? Сделайте и правда событие, пусть основная логика подписывается на него и решает, надо ли дёргать UI. Сообщение пусть конструирует UI, а не бизнес-логика, нечего ей представлением заниматься.

Answer (score 4):

Вернуться в трай после возникновения исключения невозможно.
Тестовое подключение обычно производится отдельно от полезного бд-шного траффика.
Плюс, ни кто не отменял транзакции. Завершайте транзакцию в самом конце блока трай, либо в файналли.

Comment: транзакции на клиенте - зло! :)

Comment: Зло, не спорю, но, бывают случаи, когда они очень спасали меня. Плюс, транзакцию можно провести и не на уровне бд...

Comment: Я не вношу изменения в базу данных, да и мне не интересно управлять транзакциями. При подключении к базе данных включен режим автотранзакиций.

Comment: Вообще странно, что нельзя вернуться обратно в блок трай. дебагер же может это делать. Например windbg. кто-то мне говорил такую фразу: можно вернуться обратно в блок try на строчку ошибки выполнения кода, с тем исключением, что при возникновении нового exception, этот блок try более не отловит его, т.к. он уже отработал.

Comment: Ну, дебагер на то и дебагер, чтобы контролировать код полностью. С помощью него можно не только вернуться на место создания исключения, но и выполность проивольный участок кода.

Answer (score 3):

А почему нельзя сделать просто вот так?

````
```
try
{
   // делаем исключение
}
catch (SomeEx)
{
   // обработка сообщения. возврат обратно
}
// продолжение.
```
````

> Думал еще про постпроверку, но дело в том, что подключение открывается в самых разных местах, и постпроверку версии придется также размазать по всему коду, что не есть хорошо.

Вот это тоже не совсем понятно: почему нельзя просто инкапсулировать это поведение в отдельный класс / метод?

Comment: Так нельзя сделать, потому что открытие подключения закопано глубоко.  по колстэку на 3 метода в глубину.